# Redshift distribution key NULL constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Does the distribution key in redshift ( when the distribution style is selected as KEY) must be not null or it can be null also?

Comment: Isn't it a lot quicker to make a test table and find out if you get an error message than to ask on SO?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on the distribution key from being NULL.  It is a really bad idea to use a distribution key that does contain NULLs as this will likely skew your tables distribution very badly.  All the rows with NULL in this columns (along with a percentage of the rest) will be allocated to a single slice.